# Int is nil in viewWillAppear after setting it to 1 in function - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int

Why is the Integer "int1" nil in "viewWillAppear" when I have set it to 1 in a function?

```
var int1 : Int!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("viewWillAppear")
    if int1 != nil {

        print("int1 != nil")

    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("viewDidLoad")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.willFinishLaunchingWithOptions), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching, object: nil)

}

func willFinishLaunchingWithOptions(notification: NSNotification){
    print("Launching!")
    self.int1 = 1
}
```

In the console it is printed "Launching!". When the view first loads when the app is launching I'm aware of that int1 is nil but when I segue to another view controller and back I'm expecting "int1 != 1" to be printed but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: How do you go back to your initial view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `viewWillAppear()` to validate that it is being called when you expect it to be called, and that the value is what you expect it to be?

You're calling `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from Notification Center, like @daskblinkenlight says?

I'm assuming there should be another close curly brace at the end of `viewWillAppear`? Is `"viewWillAppear"` being printed when you expect it to?

Comment: Yes I've tried setting a breakpoint and viewWillAppear() is called and as you mentioned I forgot a curly brace at the end, "viewWillAppear" is printed. I swap between view controllers using a normal storyboard segue. The problem is that the value of int1 is not 1 when viewWillAppear is called when I jump to a different view controller and back.